# Group users in pairs and mix for each round

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to match all users (as divs) with each others.
eg. 4 users -> 3 rounds to match all in pairs.
For now i have 1 round and each users are connected, but how make automatically other rounds?

```js
var divs = $(".contents");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
   j = i + 1; 
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div id='newDivforWraping"+j+"' class='new'></div>");
}
```

```css
.new
{
    width:100%; 
    border:1px solid; 
    margin:10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="postings">
    <div class="contents">1</div>
    <div class="contents">2</div>
    <div class="contents">3</div>
    <div class="contents">4</div>
    <div class="contents">5</div>
    <div class="contents">6</div>
    <div class="contents">7</div>
    <div class="contents">8</div>
</div>
```

```
var divs = $(".contents");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
   j = i + 1; 
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div id='newDivforWraping"+j+"' class='new'></div>");
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/RQNrt/74/

Comment: Even after seeing the expanded code in the fiddle, your question makes no sense

Comment: @Szmerd, Please consider adding what output you exactly need

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Are you trying to make something like a tournament bracket ?

Comment: Sorry,  yes i mean tournament like PvP with each other.